# Java Crashes when Oracle NODE FailOver occurs

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Hi Everyone,
                    My application crashes when we do the oracle node failover. Java version is 1.8.025. Below is the java crash log. Can you help me understand what is the root cause for the stack overflow exception. I know increasing the stack size will fix the issue but I guess it is a temporary fix.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x000000002ed86b87, pid=6792, tid=2532
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [oran11.dll+0x406b87]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Program Files (x86)\XXXX\XXX\XXX\hs_err_pid6792.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------


Current thread (0x000000002c19f000):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=2532, stack(0x0000000030150000,0x0000000030170000)]


siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc00000fd, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000001 0x0000000030150000


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000002ba0, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000030570bb0, RDX=0x000000003015558c
RSP=0x00000000301529c8, RBP=0x0000000030152a40, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x000000003057a4a0
R8 =0x000000003129d0e0, R9 =0x000000002ceef040, R10=0x000000003014f000, R11=0x0000000030150000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000030570bb0, R14=0x000000003129d0e0, R15=0x000000002e980000
RIP=0x000000002ed86b87, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010286


Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000301529c8)
0x00000000301529c8:   0000000000000ab0 0000000000000000
0x00000000301529d8:   000000002ecfb0d7 0000000030152a40
0x00000000301529e8:   000000002eb956d5 0000000000000000
0x00000000301529f8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a08:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a18:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a28:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a38:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a48:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a58:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a68:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a78:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a88:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152a98:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152aa8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000030152ab8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000


Instructions: (pc=0x000000002ed86b87)
0x000000002ed86b67:   d0 4d 0f 42 d3 65 4c 8b 1c 25 10 00 00 00 4d 3b
0x000000002ed86b77:   d3 73 16 66 41 81 e2 00 f0 4d 8d 9b 00 f0 ff ff
0x000000002ed86b87:   41 c6 03 00 4d 3b d3 75 f0 4c 8b 14 24 4c 8b 5c
0x000000002ed86b97:   24 08 48 83 c4 10 c3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00




Register to memory mapping:


RAX=0x0000000000002ba0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000030570bb0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000003015558c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002c19f000
RSP=0x00000000301529c8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002c19f000
RBP=0x0000000030152a40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000002c19f000
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000003057a4a0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000003129d0e0 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000002ceef040 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000003014f000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000274f6000
R11=0x0000000030150000 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000274f6000
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000030570bb0 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000003129d0e0 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000002e980000 is an unknown value




Stack: [0x0000000030150000,0x0000000030170000],  sp=0x00000000301529c8,  free space=10k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [oran11.dll+0x406b87]
C  [oran11.dll+0x37b0d7]
C  [oran11.dll+0x2156d5]
C  [oran11.dll+0x1ba8b1]
C  [oran11.dll+0x19b33e]
C  [oran11.dll+0x19e961]
C  [oran11.dll+0x205f7e]
C  [oran11.dll+0x2a622]
C  [oran11.dll+0x13b0c]
C  [oran11.dll+0xdbc0]
C  [oran11.dll+0x8ab5]
C  [oran11.dll+0x2128c3]
C  [oran11.dll+0x20effe]
C  [oran11.dll+0x1a45b8]
C  [oran11.dll+0xd61ff]
C  [oran11.dll+0xabf8d]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x149276]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x3127cb]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x314169]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x2f5d05]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x1486b4]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x282e0e]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x283bf4]
C  [oracommon11.dll+0x12c13f]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x311c6c]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x2f8659]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x24d8e8]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x1bf3ec]
C  [OraClient11.Dll+0x57d36]
C  [OCI.dll+0x44af]
C  [ocijdbc11.dll+0x1172e]
C  [ocijdbc11.dll+0x14437]
C  0x00000000037290a7


Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 3435  oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.t2cParseExecuteDescribe(Loracle/jdbc/driver/OracleStatement;JIIIZZZZ[BIBII[SI[B[CII[SII[B[CII[I[S[BIIIIZZ[Loracle/jdbc/driver/Accessor;[[[B[J[BI[CI[SIZ)I (0 bytes) @ 0x0000000003729029 [0x0000000003728c80+0x3a9]
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CStatement.executeForDescribe()V+335
J 1605 C1 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe()V (678 bytes) @ 0x00000000031cf924 [0x00000000031cbb80+0x3da4]
J 1603 C1 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout()V (1335 bytes) @ 0x00000000031f4b4c [0x00000000031ef5c0+0x558c]
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/ResultSet;+240
j  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/ResultSet;+81
j  com.test.util.DBConnection.isValid()Z+19
j  com.test.util.DBConnectionPool.getConnection()Ljava/sql/Connection;+44
j  com.test.util.NetworkObjectRegistry.getNetworkObjectFromDB(ILjava/lang/String;)Lcom/test/model/NetworkObject;+5
j  com.test.util.NetworkObjectRegistry.registerNetworkObject(ISLjava/lang/String;)Lcom/test/model/NetworkObject;+3
j  com.test.util.NetworkObjectRegistry.getNetworkObjectForFposAndCat(IS)Lcom/test/model/NetworkObject;+43
j  com.test.util.NetworkObjectRegistry.getObjectTypeKey(IS)I+3
j  com.test.util.NetworkObjectRegistry.getObjectType(IS)I+5
j  com.test.util.OperationModeUtil.checkAuthorization(SISLjava/lang/String;)Z+2
j  com.test.util.OperationModeUtil.checkAuthorization(Lcom/test/model/Outage;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+22
j  com.test.main.OutageTable.valueChanged(Ljavax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent;)V+540
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(IIZ)V+64
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Z)V+34
j  javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(Z)V+15
```

Comment: Looks to me like your ResultSet is probably too big for the memory space.  The query most likely needs rewriting.

Comment: @avgstvs Initial load up of the application is working Java crashes only when the oracle failover happens. The query is select count(1) from dual.